# How to do 3d Carousel with modifications in image's dimensions and angle

Tags: android, 3d, carousel

I need the rounded carousel affect to some set of images. I am using the below sample project for this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

I would like to reduce the image size while it's moving to background and rotate the image with some angle. Finally the output should be as below.

[image: Finally it should look like as below.]

Need help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. I have same question. Can you help me to do this same ?

Comment: @Prince did u solved this issue???

Comment: @prabhakaran I didnt get perfect effects, but used changed values in the same demo. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Comment: @Prince but i cant even download.. can u help me